How to use charisma in role play mechanics?
The scenario:
We've been playing a DnD 5e campaign for over a year. I'm playing a L8 tiefling sorcerer with dragon ancestry. We finally confronted a White Dragon, between Young and Adult age (it was already legendary but with 280HP), and quite dumb. We had skirmishes with this dragon in the past when it did some fly by attacks and we shot arrows at it so that would make diplomacy more challenging.
The dragon was standing on some tower 20 feet up and I wanted to get it down to our level in its layer. I spoke with said dragon in draconic. I rolled a 19 which gave me, with the with double proficiency bonus + charisma, a total of 30 (doesn't get much higher than this). So my pitch to the dragon (in short) was that we have become so impressed with its might, blah-blah-blah, that we want to serve it. It told me to come forward and parley. I left cover and came forward. Roleplaying continued and the dragon told me to prove my loyalty by chopping my own hand off (which I wasn't going to do, especially with it up there and out of reach). I told it that I would be honored if it came down and bit my hand off, at which point it came down, but first blocked off my party from reaching it (and me) with a wall of ice. I yapped a bit to buy a few seconds, held out my hand, and at which point the barbarian started attacking the wall of ice to break through - battle started then.
My question is:
should a 30 have resulted in a smoother interaction leading to us having an upper hand? It seems like all abilities' successes/failures are used mechanically (e.g. you succeeded in climbing or not) whereas for charisma the roll is virtually meaningless. Should the roleplay influence the roll of the dice/result, or should the roll of the dice influence more the direction of the roleplay? (Obviously completely unreasonable roleplay should make diplomacy impossible like telling a dragon to hand over its treasure.)

You rolled a 30 for what, did your DM call for a Persuasion or Deception roll?

What did you want to achieve with your pitch?

Of possible interest:  Can someone explain what I would be able to convince people to do with a 34 persuasion or deception check?, What to do when a player roleplays an extremely persuasive argument, but flubs their Persuasion check?, How should a DM resolve a smooth-talking player with a weak Charisma score PC?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The way your DM handled this is fine
You both got a great result on your skill roll and you made a credible roleplaying effort, but this does not give you a free pass to dictate what a monster or NPC will or will not do.
First, you cannot just roll a skill check whenever you want. The way it works is that the DM must determine if and what kind of check is appropriate (DMG, p. 37), set a DC, and asks you to roll. Then depending on the result they decide what happens. The DMG advises on p. 244:

The adventurers need to succeed on one or more challenging Charisma checks
to convince a hostile creature to do anything on their behalf. That said, a hostile creature might be so ill disposed toward the party that no Charisma check can improve its attitude, in which case any attempt to sway it
through diplomacy fails automatically.

So, they had every right to not even allow you to roll, but they did. So for the sake of this question, I'll assume they were OK with you to roll. If you are playing this differently, the DM should assert their rights here. For this question I'll assume they asked you to roll. By the rules, your DM did not do anything technically wrong here -- you rolled, and they told you what happens. You actually convinced the dragon to come down, too, so you were successful with your roll.
All that being said, from your question I take it that you feel this was not handled fairly, and with your lie, and your great roll and skill, you should have lured the dragon down without it taking precautions.
Is there anything to blame?
I think what you maybe can hold against your DM that at an intelligence of somewhere between 6 (for a Young White Dragon) and 8 for an Adult White Dragon, the dragon was acting pretty smart in setting up a wall to isolate you. And in my experience, playing dumb monsters smarter than they are is one of the most common DM mistakes -- it always feels unfair to the players, gamey, and not fun. Players love it if they get the better of a powerful foe like an ogre or later, a white dragon, because they tricked it. Low intelligence is a real disadvantage, and not playing it that way as the DM comes across as antagonistic.
Still, it is up to the DM to determine the degree of success, DMG p. 242

You determine the consequences of attack rolls, ability
checks, and saving throws

And the White Dragon Monster entry says

Though only moderately intelligent, white dragons have extraordinary memories. They recall every slight and defeat, and have been known to conduct malicious vendettas against creatures that have offended them.

So, it wants to bite off your hand, both as proof and to pay you back. Feels like a great rendition of the dragon. It also is understandable that even if the dragon is dumb it distrusts you, because everything you did before tells it you'll try to trick and kill it. Yes, another DM might have been more generous, but I think there is nothing really wrong with what the DM did.

1 The roll should probably not have been that hard. Sure, that the dragon had any right to distrust you, and considering you had shot it in the past, and likely were just planning to slaughter it once it is in reach of your melee weapons, no matter what you tell him, this was probably not an easy roll. But on the other hand as you say, white dragons are pretty dumb, and therefore should be easier to dupe.

Thanks. interesting answer

This is largely a matter of personal style, and 5e is particularly vague on what the "recommended" way to go about this is.  However, from my own experience running games, I can give one general piece of guidance:
No encounter hinges on one roll.
Imagine a battle.  In a combat encounter that is even vaguely tuned towards the party's level, there are going to be a lot of dice rolled.  Maybe a winning strategy or a well built character can minimize the number of rolls, but it's pretty much never going to be just one roll.  The wizard will soften up the enemies with a fireball, the barbarian will break up the front lines, and the rogue will jump in from behind to kill the fire-resistant captain.  Next round, the next part of the party's strategy will play out.
Or imagine a trapped chest being disarmed by a rogue.  You're not just going to roll for theives' tools and say "hey bingo presto, get your 200 gold."  No, there's going to be a search check, a description of the mechanism, some declared idea (I want to inch the chest open and shove a wire into the poison spray nozzle), then a trap disarming roll, then some kind of intelligence roll once the chest is open to appraise the treasure within.  Each step of the way has some kind of repercussion for failure and some kind of creativity required to win.
The same is true of a diplomatic encounter.
Since this dragon has been a regular enemy, it is completely expected that there would be some serious suspicion here.  You went into this situation with the odds against you.  That's what your initial high roll did - it allowed you to overcome the initial disadvantage you had.  In this respect, the roll did everything it was allowed to do.
Think about it like this: when you attack with a weapon, it's not "I roll to kill the goblin," it's "I roll to attack the goblin."  Maybe that attack can kill, maybe not.  So, even if you opened with some really good diplomacy, sometimes it's just not possible to do more than breach the first layer of conversational defenses.  You would need to rely on some other way of finishing the job after creating your opening - you can't just bypass an entire encounter at step 1 because that's too easy.  It would make the dragon seem gullible.

Good answer, +1.  2 cents: This -- "No encounter hinges on one roll." . . . seemed misleading to me at first, maybe something like "No encounter should hinge on one roll" captures what you're saying better?

@Jack The vast majority of things that can be resolved in one roll should be one part of a larger encounter.  While I aknowledge that cases may come up of nontrivial encounters being solved by one action, either due to player cleverness or designer oversight, I think that's rare enough that it's not worth changing up the wording for.  I suppose you're right in the fact that there's an implied "nontrivial" before the word "encounter," though.  Not worth watering down the main statement for, IMO.

Makes sense.  Either way, good points.

@good points. I didnt know how this works. thanks for the answer.
